# Run Resin (caucho.com) on port 80 in Ubuntu, using unprivileged user?

Tags: ubuntu, java, port, resin

Without getting into proxying, or port redirects, port forwards, etc, is there any native method to bind [Resin (a Java server)](http://caucho.com/resin-4.0/) to port 80, on an Ubuntu server, while Resin is started by root but then operates as an unprivileged user (www-data)?

This is on Ubuntu 10.10, running Resin from the caucho apt repository.
I know if I run & operate Resin as root, I can make it use port 80, but as you can imagine, that's not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, terminal cmds below.
These commands assume you're running Ubuntu 10, and have installed Resin via it's apt repositories.
In my case, www-data will be running authbind, with a userid of 33, which you'll see below:

```
# aptitude install authbind
# nano -w /etc/authbind/byuid/33
# chown www-data. /etc/authbind/byuid/33
# chmod 700 /etc/authbind/byuid/33
# nano -w /etc/init.d/resin
```

While editing /etc/init.d/resin, find:

```
start)
```

Below that, find:

```
su $USER
```

Delete that line, replace with:

```
su $USER -s /usr/local/bin/authbind --deep /bin/bash -c """$JAVA -jar $RESIN_HOME/lib/resin.jar $ARGS start""" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Find:

```
stop)
```

Below that, find:

```
su $USER
```

Delete that line, replace with:

```
su $USER -s /bin/bash -c """$JAVA -jar $RESIN_HOME/lib/resin.jar $ARGS shutdown""" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Write the file & exit (use CTRL+O, CTRL+X)

Now you need to edit resin config:

```
# nano -w /etc/resin/resin.xml
```

Make sure that your HTTP port is set to 80 (I believe it is as default, as Resin runs as rot by default), and make sure the following 2 lines are uncommented in the file as well:

www-data
   www-data

Save & exit (CTRL+O, CTRL+X)

Now start Resin:

```
# service resin start
```

Comment: Found out after all this, that Resin supports running as a user/group natively :-)

Comment: In resin.xml, just edit the user/group xml tags. Haven't found any issues with that. The procedure above can also be altered and reused for running Tomcat (or TCat) as non-root.